# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType _ while using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I wrote 3 python scripts and all of them are working fine when I run them with python3.6. Now I wanted to build executable files for each of these scripts using pyinstaller. Please Note that I cannot install pyinstaller on the computer due to the rules in my institution, so I downloaded the pyinstaller package and run the pyinstaller.py with python3.6 from the directory and it works fine. 
The problem which I'm facing right now is the following: 
Building the .exe works for one script without problems, but if I try to build the other 2 scripts I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyinstaller.py", line 15, in <module>
    run()
  File "/home/akaroui/PyInstaller-3.3.1/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 94, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/home/akaroui/PyInstaller-3.3.1/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/home/akaroui/PyInstaller-3.3.1/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 791, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/home/akaroui/PyInstaller-3.3.1/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 737, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 22, in <module>
  File "/home/akaroui/PyInstaller-3.3.1/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 213, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/home/akaroui/PyInstaller-3.3.1/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 161, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/home/akaroui/PyInstaller-3.3.1/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 472, in assemble
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "/home/akaroui/PyInstaller-3.3.1/PyInstaller/building/imphook.py", line 414, in post_graph
    self._process_hook_func()
  File "/home/akaroui/PyInstaller-3.3.1/PyInstaller/building/imphook.py", line 433, in _process_hook_func
    self._hook_module.hook(hook_api)
  File "/home/akaroui/PyInstaller-3.3.1/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-_tkinter.py", line 245, in hook
    hook_api.add_datas(_collect_tcl_tk_files(hook_api))
  File "/home/akaroui/PyInstaller-3.3.1/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-_tkinter.py", line 208, in _collect_tcl_tk_files
    tcl_root, tk_root = _find_tcl_tk(hook_api)
  File "/home/akaroui/PyInstaller-3.3.1/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-_tkinter.py", line 159, in _find_tcl_tk
    bins = selectImports(hook_api.__file__)
  File "/home/akaroui/PyInstaller-3.3.1/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", line 493, in selectImports
    xtrapath = [os.path.dirname(pth)]
  File "/usr/local/python/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py", line 154, in dirname
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Does anyone have an idea how can I fix this problem ?

Here are more information : 
Using Linux - Python3.6
the Scripts where I get the problem do open files and modify their content, and also run some pdflatex-scripts. They are as I mentioned working fine when I run them with Python, the only problem is building the .exe from them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An error for generating an exe file using pyinstaller - typeerror: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138898/an-error-for-generating-an-exe-file-using-pyinstaller-typeerror-expected-str)