# An error for generating an exe file using pyinstaller - typeerror: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am trying to build an `.exe` file from `.py` file using `pysinstaller` and Python 3.7.2.

It worked with Python 3.6; then I re-installed the last version of Python (3.7.2) and tried to generate an exe file, but pyinstaller barfs.

Below is the error report I get.

```
(venv) C:\Users\user\Desktop\untitled1>pyinstaller test.py

53 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
53 INFO: Python: 3.7.2
54 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
58 INFO: wrote C:\Users\user\Desktop\untitled1\test.spec
60 INFO: UPX is not available.
61 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\untitled1', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\untitled1']
61 INFO: checking Analysis
187 INFO: checking PYZ
236 INFO: checking PKG
237 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
238 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\untitled1\venv\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 11, in  <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.4', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\untitled1\venv\lib\site- packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))   
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\untitled1\venv\lib\site- packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 784, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 29, in <module>   
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 424, in __init__
    strip_binaries=self.strip, upx_binaries=self.upx,   
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 196, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()   
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 273, in assemble
    pylib_name = os.path.basename(bindepend.get_python_library_path())   
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ntpath.py", line 214, in basename
    return split(p)[1]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ntpath.py", line 183, in split
    p = os.fspath(p) TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I am having the same error. did you find any answer to this error?

Answer (score 18):

I found the following solution: replace `bindepend.py` from `<myProject_path>\venv\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend` with the file provided by **Loran425** on github [here](https://github.com/Loran425/pyinstaller/commit/14b6e65642e4b07a4358bab278019a48dedf7460)

Comment: I did this and the build was also successful. But the application just closes on opening when opened from dist folder.
When opened from inside build folder, it shows 'my_path'/python37.dll Module not Found error
Any solution?

Comment: Worked for me, thank you. Would be more sustainable to have a new version of this file committed for PyInstaller project

Comment: It has since been committed. It's not in a released PyInstaller but it's definitely in `master` today!

Answer (score 2):

As I have read from many forums [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3942) and [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2985) and discussions regarding this issue caused by Pyinstaller. 
If you are using Pycharm or any virtual environment. Unfortunatelly Pycharm creates its local vertual environment in `venv`path once you indicate the `interpreter`. So, you should set the external tool (pyinstaller) to the real path of your python 3.7 .exe as the picture shows here. [image]

For **Linux** users, follow my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906539/configuring-pycharm-to-run-pyinstaller/54541623#54541623).

Comment: Working directory is the directory where your project is stored, right?

Comment: @KunjMehta correct, it is also the directory where all of the imported libraries of your project are stored.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem occurs when I'm using the standard library's `venv`, but not when I'm using `virtualenv`. (However I had to use `virtualenv==16.1.0` because of [another bug](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4064).)

Answer (score 1):

The bug was resolved in version 3.6 of PyInstaller. Just update and will work fine.

Comment: I had to remove uuid to upgrade past 3.5.  uuid is now built-in but some packages will install it as a req because of python 2 compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

It may be from an ill-formed spec file, something as simple (yet difficult to find) as a commented or missing argument.

When I comment out `name` in `exe`,

```py
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          # name='my_app',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          icon='resources/icons/icon.ico',
          version='resources/version/version.py')
```

I get the following traceback:

```sh
146666 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) c:\projects\my-env\app\qc\tools\my_app\build\my_app_old\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lorem\Anaconda3\envs\my-env\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "C:\Users\lorem\Anaconda3\envs\my-env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\lorem\Anaconda3\envs\my-env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lorem\Anaconda3\envs\my-env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 720, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\lorem\Anaconda3\envs\my-env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 667, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "my_app_old.spec", line 49, in <module>
    version='resources/version/version.py')
  File "C:\Users\lorem\Anaconda3\envs\my-env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 382, in __init__
    self.name = os.path.join(CONF['distpath'], os.path.basename(self.name))
  File "C:\Users\lorem\Anaconda3\envs\my-env\lib\ntpath.py", line 214, in basename
    return split(p)[1]
  File "C:\Users\lorem\Anaconda3\envs\my-env\lib\ntpath.py", line 183, in split
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

The application builds when `name` is included.