# TypeError in cx-freeze exe

Tags: python, cx-freeze

im very new so pls dont hate.

I recently built my exe from my py with cx-freeze but when i open it, it shows this :

Does anyone know how i can fix this?

````
    module.run()
  File "C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 37, in run
    exec(code, {'__name__': '__main__'})
  File "Hellofresh.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 65, in figlet_format
    fig = Figlet(font, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 794, in __init__
    self.setFont()
  File "C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 801, in setFont
    self.Font = FigletFont(font=self.font)
  File "C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 126, in __init__
    self.data = self.preloadFont(font)
  File "C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 136, in preloadFont
    if pkg_resources.resource_exists('pyfiglet.fonts', fn):
  File "C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1134, in resource_exists
    return get_provider(package_or_requirement).has_resource(resource_name)
  File "C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 364, in get_provider
    return _find_adapter(_provider_factories, loader)(module)
  File "C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1392, in __init__
    self.module_path = os.path.dirname(getattr(module, '__file__', ''))
  File "C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 223, in dirname
    return split(p)[0]
  File "C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 185, in split
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType```
````

Comment: Looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138898/an-error-for-generating-an-exe-file-using-pyinstaller-typeerror-expected-str), can you give it a look?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An error for generating an exe file using pyinstaller - typeerror: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138898/an-error-for-generating-an-exe-file-using-pyinstaller-typeerror-expected-str)

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem many times.
To fix this you can uninstall XX freeze module by running the command:

```
pip uninstall cx_freeze
```

And then reinstall the module by the command:

```
pip install cx_freeze
```

Then your error might be fixed. But if it is not fixed try reinstalling the Python.