# expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not BytesIO

Tags: python, pyinstaller

So, I'm trying to make a .exe from a .py with pyinstaller. It compiles without raising any error but I get an error from running the .exe :

```py
Failed to execute script 'Editor' due to unhandled exception:
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not BytesIO
```

and the worst thing is that it says

```py
Failed to obtain/convert traceback!
```

under it so I don't know where to search.

I'm already using pyinstaller for another project with the same coding environment (VSC) and it works fine.

I'm using pygame and numpy, but I also did in the other project I mentionned.

I tried some solution found on SO (ex: [An error for generating an exe file using pyinstaller - typeerror: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138898/an-error-for-generating-an-exe-file-using-pyinstaller-typeerror-expected-str)) but it wasn't the same error message anyway.

I am currently trying to replicate the error.

Comment: Have you thoroughly tested your script in `.py` form to see if you can reproduce the error?

Comment: "I'll edit this question with a link when I'll have the problematic exe on my github." No, Stack Overflow does not operate on this basis. If the problem can't be reproduced in source code, in the question itself, then for our purposes it cannot be reproduced at all. We *especially* are not going to expect people to *trust an arbitrary executable file* in order to observe the problem. Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and consider other techniques for isolating the problem.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't thought about that. I can link the source code instead if needed. And it the script does work if executed as a .py through VSC so I have no idea of what could cause this.

Comment: No, do not link the source code. Figure out a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and then put the necessary source code *in the question itself*.

Comment: I'll try that then. But again, I have no idea of what could cause the issue since the error window says "Failed to obtain/convert traceback!".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by updating my libraries...

Comment: 90% it was you using the pygame default font in your program. It's a bit better on more recent pygame versions but it still breaks on `onefile`, I believe.

Comment: I was using the 'system' font so I don't think that's it. And by 'system' font I mean : `font = pg.font.SysFont('system', 36)`

Comment: But if I can’t find a font named “system” it will use the default font.